# AWS Athena yields wrong st_centroid result due to outdated Trino version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, trino

The query below on current AWS Athena version 3 gives a wrong result for the centroid, which lies way below the polygon (POINT (6.127790214246207 46.2084751184263)). The exact same query in PostGIS gives the correct POINT (6.1278266666666665 46.20875).

```sql
WITH poly AS (
    SELECT st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON ((
        6.12784 46.20880,
        6.12780 46.20873,
        6.12784 46.20872,
        6.12784 46.20880))') AS polygon
)
SELECT st_centroid(poly.polygon) as centroid_athena, poly.polygon
FROM poly
```

I also checked this for various Trino versions. The current Trino version 436 yields the correct result. Version 369 from roughly a year ago produces the same wrong output as AWS Athena.

**Does anyone know how often AWS updates their underlying Trino and when this can be expected to be fixed?**
**Also ideas for workarounds on Athena would be appreciated.**